# seperation of the blender modes?

Tags: animation, blenderkit

I like using Blender, and have used it for various applications. but currently, I find that I am not using ALL of the features this program provides. This got me thinking, would it be possible to separate the various modes that Blender has to offer? (i.e. making geometry, video editing, model animation). I would personally love it if I could only download a version of the video editor, and a version that lets me pose objects. Like SFM (Source Film Maker). as I don't want to worry about screwing up a project by somehow messing with one property that has nothing to do with my current project.

Best wishes!

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. And - just my opinion - this makes no sense. So you would have multiple Blender variations/apps. Each one with different versions and you have to update each one of them (manually). You have to open and close different apps multiple times for more complex tasks. And even worse - because a lot of stuff is in common like cursor handling, rendering, UI ...the sum of all apps would be much bigger than just one Blender version.

Comment: it's a bit like Excel - one Excel version for inputting data, one version for creating diagrams and one for calculation...which ... in my opinion makes no sense.

Comment: @Chris i agree. this would make no sense.

Comment: Apart from the other opinions, it's also completely off-topic here!